# Can Hiragana or Katakana stand alone?

Tags: kanji, hiragana, katakana

Writing Japanese requires a mix of Kanji and Hiragana, usually some Katakana as well.
I have read that some Kanji characters can be replaced with Hiragana characters for easier writing.

My question is: can all Kanji characters be replaced? Can I write Japanese only with Hiragana or only in Katakana and be fully understood?

Comment: if you get a book for a japanese toddler, it is usually written in all hiragana. So mostly for that level of communication

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kanji can always be replaced with hiragana, for example

- if the writer cannot recall the correct kanji, or
- the intended reader is likely to have a limited knowledge of kanji (eg children), or
- the kanji for the word is not in general use, or
- pretty much any reason you want.

The use of katakana, however, is usually reserved for borrow words, emphasis and so on.

So writing using only hiragana is both valid and understandable, with the caveat that in many cases doing so will make your writing very awkward reading, and can introduce ambiguity into your writing, for example in the case of homophones (words that share the same pronunciation but generally different kanji).

Compare the following two ways of writing the same well-known sentence:

> 庭には二羽鶏がいる
>   にわにはにわにわとりがいる

I think all Japanese speakers would agree that the kanji version is much easier reading and much clearer than the hiragana-only version.

Writing using only katakana will be more awkward to read because it is not generally expected for Japanese words to be written in katakana, and for the same reason would probably be considered invalid, except in certain circumstances like to put emphases on pronunciation. If you did decide to write this way for some reason, however, it would be just as understandable as writing in only hiragana as the two characters sets have a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: 「うらにわにはにわにわにはにわにわとりがいる」は？w

Comment: Haha, I'm also interested. I wonder if it might be 裏庭には庭、庭には二羽鶏がいる?　Or, 裏庭には二羽、庭には二羽鶏がいる?

Comment: [This](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5748/1272) answer to a different question by Tsuyoshi Ito is interesting and also relevant here.

Comment: @dainichi and ジョン-- The latter (normally). ^o^♪ (We also have わたしははは、ははははははとわらう.) ww

Comment: @Chocolate:  すもももももももものうち！

Comment: @istrascisan, Lol~ yes, so that's why we can't do without kanji, because writing just in hiragana or katakana can often be so ambiguous that it may cause confusions such as ゆで卵/茹でた孫/気が乗らん/飢餓の乱/去年から海外に住み始めました/去年から貝が胃に棲み始めました  http://www.kanken.or.jp/henkan/4happyou.html#05round

Comment: In response to the quite old comment aboveI respectfully disagree that kanji is the only way to prevent ambiguity. Spaces do quite nicely:

Comment: ゆでたまご／ゆでた まご／きが のらん／きがの らん／きょねん から かいがいに すみはじめました／きょねん から かいが いに すみはじめました. With some basic ground rules, such as whether or not to put spaces before particles, context clears most everything up just like it does in speech. Japanese video games have been doing this for decades now. If you really want, you can also add a diacritic for pitch accent and end all real ambiguity. In English we have the same problem in artificial, amusing sentences like "fish fish fish fish fish fish fish fish". It's not a real problem.

Comment: I hope we're not putting English up as the gold standard of clear communication :) Seriously though, I see your point - word boundary identification is a bigger problem than homophones, and spaces fix this. As somebody for whom literature has been the main source of reading practice over the years, I'm still rather thrown by old kana-only video games and find myself reaching for a dictionary even more than usual. I'm not at all sure if native speakers are also thrown by this to any extent, but I think it's fair to say that appropriate use of kanji makes for more familiar, comfortable reading.

Answer (score 4):

As a minor addendum to other answers, there is another problem with writing in kana only: reading speed.

For someone who has knowledge of the relevant kanji, reading the kanji version isn't just a way around homophones and ambiguity, it is actually faster.

The reading speed difference gets bigger as your reader's level goes up and the more you stick to 'conventional' kanji assignments.

I am not a native speaker, nor anywhere near, but I notice my reading speed drop significantly in 'all kana' situations, probably by a factor of 2-5.  That factor has continued to increase with my literacy level, so I imagine a native speaker would suffer quite a serious slow down.

This is consistent with some research that suggests fluent readers dont really read individual characters.. they recognize whole words or even phrases at a time based on visual components that are distinctive combined with contextual predictions.  If you use an unconventional spelling, eg all kana or unusual kanji, you change the visual form and the reader is less likely to 'shortcut' recognition, perhaps causing a 'stumble' where they have to read more closely.  (Intentionally causing such stumbles is a valid technique, and may partially explain why kana are sometimes used for emphasis)

Your readers will thank you if you make the effort to learn to write to the conventions they are used to.

Answer (score 3):

"The Tale of Genji", which is regarded as Japan's first novel, in all hiragana. Wikipedia mentions that modern day Japanese have difficulty understanding the book as sometimes there's two or more possible meanings for what's written, though.

Comment: Probably the bigger impediment to understanding is that it's written in [Early Middle Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Middle_Japanese), and that it avoids directly mentioning characters.

Comment: Genji is in fact not the first novel and no one knows what style the original work is written in because the original source is missing.

Comment: I think Tosa Nikki (土佐日記) is famous for being written (almost) only with hiragana. The author, Ki no Tsurayuki (紀貫之), pretended that he is female and wrote the text in hiragana because hiragana was used by women in those days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all Kanji characters can be replaced by hiragana, by katakana, and by a mixture of them. However, as other answers show, two sentences with Kanji may map to the same single sequence of hiragana or of katanaka. Such a sequence is understandable, but may be understood as multiple meanings.

For example, in old days (probably around early 20th century), Japanese telegraphy messages were all written only with katakana, as far as I know from movies. Even more, it seems to have been customary to omit the dots and circles (゛,゜) and commas and periods (、,。) to save the number of characters.
A famous message is

> ハハキトクスクカエレ

which may be written with Kanji as

> 母危篤。すぐ帰れ。

which means "Your mother is dying. Come home in a hurry."
I think people did understand this kind of katakana-only messages.
For more examples, please see
[電報 Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%BB%E5%A0%B1#.E7.A4.BE.E4.BC.9A.E3.83.BB.E6.96.87.E5.8C.96.E3.81.B8.E3.81.AE.E5.BD.B1.E9.9F.BF).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to write anything in Japanese using only Hiragana and Katakana which are the phonetic systems. Kanji are ideograms, so they do not represent specific sounds but ideas. In Latin languages, kanjis would be like the root meanings of the words.

Lets see for example the following 2 words in English:

- God
- Theology

If we decompose this words into their roots it would be:

- "God" means "God"
- "Theos" also means "God" in the original Greek, and "log" means "to speak", which in turn [developed into the English suffix -logy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/-logy#:%7E:text=%2Dlogy%20is%20a%20suffix%20in,%2D%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%AF%CE%B1%20(%2Dlogia).&text=The%20suffix%20has%20the%20sense,%5Ba%20certain%20subject%5D%22.) that means "the study [of something in particular]". Therefore, "Theology" means "the study of God/Religion".

Well, with this example in mind, in Japanese they will use the same kanji to say "God" and to say "Theo", because the kanji by itself represents the idea of "God". Depending on the context, the sound will change to fit the natural variations of spoken language.

That's why when learning Japanese, it is important to learn first the phonetic systems (Hiragana and Katakana) and after that climb to kanjis which are way more complex.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Japanese Stack Exchange! while your answer is useful, the last paragraph discussing Japanese learning itself would belong to the meta stack exchange. Also note that recommending a specific site to learn hiragana and katakana is totally unrelated to the original question, so it could be seen as spam. Would you mind to remove it? Thank you!

Comment: `Teology` <-- Theology?